# Can a deeper ITM call be cheaper than a less deep ITM call for same expiry date

Tags: call-options, yahoo-finance

In this option chain for [SPY Apr 25 calls](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=SPY&m=2014-04-25)

the one with a strike of 170.50 has a lower price than the one with a strike of 171. But why is this? 170.50 call is deeper ITM than 171, so it should be more expensive, right?

Comment: Tip: When referring to quotes that can change, please include a screenshot (as well as the link)... This way we could also see what column/item you may be referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at last trade. The current bid/ask is more relevant. 
This issue is addressed in your [recent question on SPY options](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30202/does-spy-option-prices-fluctuate-as-much-as-its-underlying) as it relates to volume and current validity of posted prices.

Comment: Ah I see. Bid/Ask is more relevant, needed to hear that one more time.

Comment: And even then, B/A is not as real time as stock quotes, as volume on most strikes is minimal. You really need the broker quote to decide on a trade.

Comment: Yes, it is not real time, it is 15 min delayed. Is that not enough for the retail investor? That plans to hold the option at least for a week and only trades options with DTE > 1 month

Comment: That's not what I meant, the B/A itself may be stale, beyond 15 min. Consider, there are hundreds of strikes/dates. The market maker isn't going to update every one without any kind of request for a real quote. When I place an order, I'll frequently see a real B/A that's not quite near what what was showing on the system.